# Volley Error on Api calling

Tags: android

Am trying to fetch a result from an api using volley using the following snipet

```
 Set<String> tags= new HashSet<String>()  ;
                tags.add("geethu");
                tags.add("gautham");
                tags.add("gauri");

                JSONObject deviceInfo = new JSONObject();
                deviceInfo.put("Platform", "gcm");
                deviceInfo.put("Handle", "handle");
                deviceInfo.put("Tags", new JSONArray(tags));

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST, "http://172........", deviceInfo,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                                Log.e("Please output",jsonObject.toString());
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener (){

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                      //  Log.d(App.TAG,volleyError.toString());
                    }
                }
                );

                jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new

                        DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)); 
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and am getting an output as 
     [8361] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://domian/..........

plz help me to find out what I am doing wrong

Comment: response code 500 means error on server side probably

Comment: response code 500 means internal server error. You need to debug at your server side to find out solution.